# Foundation classes, check for nil after alloc init

Tags: objective-c, macos, foundation, nsmutablestring

I need a mutable string in a critical function of my application. I do this:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Is there any reason whatsoever that my `string` may not have been allocated/ initialized. Should I check for:

```
if(nil == string)
{
   // Inform the caller we failed to get a mutable string
   // return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's *very* unlikely to be `nil` in this scenario, but not guaranteed.

For example: You must consider that the implementation has the ability to return `nil` when/if an allocation fails (the object itself requires a heap allocation, and perhaps its innards do also).

Panic handlers (in C) often employ static arrays to step around this possibility.